# Wordpress plugin to store base URL as variable?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Is there a plugin that takes any URLs in the post/page content and stores the base url portion as a variable?

For example, store http://www.mydomain.com/about as {$base_url}about

Would be nice for changing URLs around.

Comment: So the plugin modifies the source-code on disk? Or what do you mean by *variable*?

Comment: Plugin modifies the database content.

Comment: Database content has no variables. Please elaborate.

Comment: Stored as a variable that would be parsed in PHP when it's rendered back.

Comment: Hi Ian, what is the problem you are trying to solve? Can you give us an example?

Comment: This plugin does almost exactly what I'd like: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/url-shortcodes/. The only thing I'd like though is for it to replace absolute urls with the shortcode before save.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to edit your theme, you can use the [URL Shortcodes plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/url-shortcodes/) to produce absolute URLs that you can use in your posts and pages.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/url-shortcodes/

---

**Update:** If it's to make your WordPress database more portable, you can just use WordPress' native Import/Export functions to bring your content to a new host/domain.

If you need to change ***all*** the links in your post content, you can use a plugin like [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) to change the content within your database:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/

Comment: This looks really close to what I want. If only it would automatically detect the base url and replace it with the short code before saving.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
echo get_bloginfo('url').'/about';
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can get all of the bloginfo from that function.

Source:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo